# Can we have the history of questions visited in the App?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Sometimes on Stack Exchange I visit multiple questions related the same topic to collect the best answers. Unfortunately, with the app, I have no simple way to return to a previously visited one, unless I noted down the title of the page. This leads me to fall back using the browser when I wish to make such kind of analysis.

Therefore I'd like to see one or more of these improvements in a future version of the app:

- a history of the questions visited
- a "Previous" button (the "Back" command currently just leads to the Feed page)
- a "Bookmark" command (I'd prefer not to abuse the "Favorite" command for that)

What are the opinions of you fellow users about this (or are these functionalities already present and I simply missed them?)

Comment: Why would SO spend time reimplementing features that already exist *in your browser*? Just open questions in new tabs from the search page.

Comment: Obviously I can do everything in the browser, but what is the point of the Android app then?

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247799/forward-button-and-or-history) a cross-site/MSE duplicate?